# Jersey with Selectable Entity Filtering stops responding without SELECT on URI

Tags: java, rest, jersey, wso2, moxy

I'm trying to improve my services with [Entity Data Filtering Dynamic and Configurable Query Parameters](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.22.2/examples/entity-filtering-selectable). All resources responds correctly on GET. When I execute POST methods the server freezes. App Server runs out of memory.

**QUESTION:** Someone knows why this is happening? I'm doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: With LoggingFilter.class activated its possible to see confirmation response in others situations, not only with POST methods.

- Works

  (*GET*) /rest/domain/Entity/1?select=id,name
- Server stops responding

  (*GET*) /rest/domain/Entity/1

In the second request, server receives it and LoggingFilter show me Status Code 200. So I think the problem is something on marshaller.

**CONFIG:**

The app is deployed at WSO2 AS 5.2.1.

ApplicationConfig class:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfig() {

        property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
        property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);
        property(MarshallerProperties.BEAN_VALIDATION_MODE, BeanValidationMode.NONE);

        register(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class);
        property(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.QUERY_PARAM_NAME, "select");

        register(new MoxyJsonConfig().setFormattedOutput(true).resolver());

    }
}
```

Error.log

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.eclipse.persistence.core.queries.CoreAttributeGroup.newItem(CoreAttributeGroup.java:711)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.core.queries.CoreAttributeGroup.getItem(CoreAttributeGroup.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.core.queries.CoreAttributeGroup.addAttribute(CoreAttributeGroup.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.core.queries.CoreAttributeGroup.addAttribute(CoreAttributeGroup.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.ObjectGraphImpl.addAttributeNodes(ObjectGraphImpl.java:36)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:141)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createSubgraphs(MoxyObjectProvider.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.createObjectGraph(MoxyObjectProvider.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.internal.MoxyObjectProvider.transform(MoxyObjectProvider.java:76)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging a co-worker found out that occurs because I have bidirectional entities.

Let's say we have Customer e Address:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Address address;

}

@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID")
    @MapsId
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="address")
    private Customer customer;

}
```

In this case the Selectable filter ignores **@XmlInverseReference** when it tries to built ObjectGraph and it goes OOM.